# Modeling repeated measures in a lme model (R)

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

Given one between-subjects (group: 2 groups), one within-subjects (time: 2 timepoints), and one continuous covariate, how would the syntax look for repeated measures data using lme in R?

At the moment, the dataset is organized in a long fashion, so that all participants are repeated in the dataframe with a score from timepoint 1 and timepoint 2. Example as below:

```
ID    group    score(dv)    time
01      A        5             1
02      A        2             1
03      B        4             1
04      B        6             1
01      A        3             2
02      A        4             2
03      B        6             2
04      B        7             2
```

I originally had:

```
lme(score ~ group + time + group*time, random=list(~1|ID), data)
```

However, that did not seem correct, given that time might cause additional variance (?)...
I was then looking into something like this but it was unclear what the syntax actually adds to the model...

```
lme(score ~ group + time + group*time, random=list(~1|ID:time), data=d)
```

Could anyone provide guidance on the organization of the model?

Thanks!